# MonoGame Cross-Platform Conditional Compilation Symbols

Tags: c#, cross-platform, monogame, mono

**What are the possible compiler directives for MonoGame?**

For example, [XNA contained directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd282469.aspx) for `WINDOWS`, `XBOX`/`XBOX360`, and `WINDOWS_PHONE`.

I've also seen `DIRECTX` and `OPENGL`, but **when would you need to leverage those?**

---

Supported Platforms:

- PC
- Windows 8 Store App
- Linux
- Android
- OUYA
- Mac
- iOS
- Playstation Mobile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look [inside each project file on github](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/tree/develop/MonoGame.Framework) you can see the constants defined for each platform. I've extracted them here:

- Android - TRACE;ANDROID;GLES;OPENGL
- Linux - LINUX;OPENGL
- MacOS - MONOMAC;OPENGL
- Ouya - TRACE;ANDROID;GLES;OPENGL;OUYA
- PSMobile - DEBUG;PSM
- Windows - DEBUG;TRACE;WINDOWS;DIRECTX;WINDOWS_MEDIA_SESSION
- Windows8 - TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINRT;WINDOWS_STOREAPP;DIRECTX;DIRECTX11_1;WINDOWS_MEDIA_ENGINE
- WindowsGL - TRACE;WINDOWS;OPENGL
- WindowsPhone - TRACE;DEBUG;SILVERLIGHT;WINDOWS_PHONE;WINRT;DIRECTX
- iOS - IOS;GLES;OPENGL

Comment: I never knew those were stored in the project files. They hold all kinds of goodies!

Answer (score 1):

in addition to the other answer for windows UWP apps you can use:

```
#if WINDOWS_UAP
    // windows UWP specific code
#endif
```